# Pasing paramter values from a formula in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

I have created an automated report system, that uses a formula to run a crystal report file.

When the report file has a SQL view linked to it, the formula sent is just the criteria that the report should show Ie "{PAY_TRANS_REPORT_DATA_VIEW.PAYDT} IN #startDT# to #endDT#"

However, I have some reports that use stored procedures which have parameters required. 
My question, is how do I send these parameter values to the report?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the name of the report you want to pass a parameter is `Report1` then you can pass your parameter, `parameter1`, to your report with the following way:

```
ReportClass.SetParameterValue("parameter1",parameter1);
```

The `ReportClass` is the class that's associated with the `Report1`.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Crystal Reports sucks. Unfortunately, I am working on it currently and I have experienced a lot of problems.

Comment: Yes I've solved my problem. Been trying to work it out for about a month now. I was looking in completely the wrong place and your reply made me look in the right area. Cheers :) Agree that crystal sucks. It's powerful in what it can do, it's just a ballache to get it to do what you want it to do.

Comment: @Willdot glad to hear about this. I asked because you hadn't marked my answer as a solution. Anyway I am glad that I helped.

Comment: My mistake. New to the site as a member. Usually just search. Forgot about marking as the answer. Cheers.